# Wordpress appearance button

Tags: plugins, theme-customizer

Is it possible to place an appearance button on wordpress site. For example to make background bit dark or bit light or other colour. This feature is available on native apps. If it can be done on wordpress site then plz answer how. Thanks

Comment: Where would this be - in the admin pages, in the theme configuration, or on the site for users to use? Yes, you can make arbitrary CSS changes from Appearance, Customize, Additional CSS so it would be possible to make buttons to do that too, or for end users store some customisation in a cookie or local data storage and apply at page load. Changing image colours would be more difficult, but could be written. What precisely do you want to do? Do you have an example of an app or other site that does this you can point us at?

Comment: At the front end for users.